# Leaving a J1 program early, but returning on an ESTA?

Tags: usa, j-visa

I'm currently on a J1 visa working in the United States, my Visa is valid until the end of November but I am considering leaving my job early, maybe during August.

I am planning on traveling to other places, but want to come back to the United States on a holiday with some friends for a few weeks at the end of October. Because I would have left my job can I return on my J1 Visa (which would still be valid) or could I apply for an ESTA?

Answer (score 1):

Your J1 visa is still valid, but you cannot use it to enter the US unless you are returning to resume your J1 program, which you are not doing. You could visit on the Visa Waiver Program if you are eligible.